# IOS equivalent for Android's broadcast receiver

Tags: android, ios

Has IOS an Equivalent for Android's Broadcast Receiver that listens even if the App is not in the foreground?

What I specifically need is to listen for incoming Bluetooth Connections (which is quite easily done on Android by using the Intent BluetoothDevice.ACL_CONNECTED). What I found so far on IOS is [CBPeripheralManager.startAdvertising](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising) but I still do not know how I get notified when a connection was actually established.

Are there any options that I am not aware of that might help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've build an BLE app in the past before and I used [this pod](https://github.com/steamclock/bluejay#listen-restoration) to do so. Gives your app a callback from background when the connection is restored and simplifies working with bluetooth in iOS. Hope it helps!